How to correctly initiate an http2 request in python?
The same request, when I use Postman to initiate the request, Fiddler displays it as http1.1 protocol, but when I look at the requests listed by Network in Chrome browser, it displays as http2. I successfully requested in Chrome browser and Postman, but failed in Python. I tried to initiate an http2 request using the httpx library, but still couldn't make the request successfully.
import json

import httpx

client = httpx.Client(http2=True)

url = "https://api.dhldanhao.com/waybill/listForCodes"

payload = {
  "page_size": "",
  "begin_time": "1722960000",
  "end_time": "",
  "types": "USPS",
  "codes": "41035",
  "sn_status": "1",
  "start_address": ""
}
headers = {


  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'origin': 'https://www.dhldanhao.com',
  'priority': 'u=1, i',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


response = client.request("POST", url, headers=headers, content=json.dumps(payload))

print(response.http_version)
print(response.text)

The above is Python code, and the response is a 403 status code.
But I found in Postman that the actual request address is an IPv6 address.

